# Cambiar color a un icono

Tags: html, css

me preguntaba como es que google hace esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a lo que me refiero es cambiarle el color a un icono que esta como background.
He estado intentado por mi cuenta hacer lo mismo pero este es mi resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Tampoco he podido quitarle este espacio este div

[image: Tampoco he podido quitarle este espacio este div]

Si alguien tiene las respuestas a mis preguntas le agradeceria.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede cambiar el color del icono y del background de la siguiente manera:
1.- Primero debes asegurarte que tu icono también sea un svg.
2.-Para cambiar el color del icono, en css se pone: fill: black

3.- Para cambiar el color del background de un icono (tu pregunta) se pone un `<button class="boton"> <svg> </svg> </button>` y asi solo le cambias el color del background del boton:

```
.boton{
  background-color: #green;
}
```